# How do I make Text Mesh appear five seconds later and disappear from the scene in unity3d

Tags: unity, unityscript, mesh, text

I have a text mesh in my scene. I don't want the test to show right when the scene starts . I want to text to show up in the scene five or ten seconds later on the screen and than the text disappear after five seconds.  I only got one error . Here is my script :

{

```css
   using UnityEngine;
   using System.Collections;
   using UnityEngine.UI;
   
   public class oik : MonoBehaviour
   {
       private Text text;
       public float timeShown;
   
       void ShowMessage(string message, float timeToShow = 10)
       {
           StartCoroutine(ShowMessageCoroutine(message, timeToShow));
       }
       
       IEnumerator ShowMessageCoroutine(string message, float timeToShow = 10)
       {
           while (timeShown < timeToShow)
           {
               timeShown += Time.deltaTime;
               yield return null;
           }
 
           text.text = " The Reqiure Score is 1700" ;
       }
   }
```

}

Comment: What one error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

You would call the `ShowMessage` method in your class's `Start` method. That way the timer will start and after ten seconds the text is displayed.

To remove it after another five seconds you add below `text.text = ...`:

```
timeShown += Time.deltaTime;
if (timeShown >= timeToShow + 5)
    text.text = "";
```